# Prevent same javascript function being called multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function **initStandardProviders**() which is being rendered when I load the application and the same function is loaded from diffrent modules as well. Is there an option to prevent this function from being loaded multiple time inside the same function?

```
function initStandardProviders(){
//A random function which should be loaded only once.
}
```

Comment: Take a look at singleton pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use closure for these purposes

```
 var makeFunctionCalledOnce = function(fn){
    let called = false;
    return function(...args){
        if(!called){
            called = true;
            fn.call(this,...args);
        }
    }
  }
```

Now you can transpose **any** function to a "once called function"

```
function initStandardProviders(){
//A random function which should be loaded only once.
}

let newInitStandardProviders = makeFunctionCalledOnce(initStandardProviders);

// now just call newInitStandardProviders on runtime instead of initStandardProviders
```

Comment: If this solves your query please make sure to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in an IIFE, and toggle it on when run. If the flag is already on, don't do anything:

```
const initStandardProviders = (() => {
  let haveRun = false;
  return () => {
    if (haveRun) {
      return;
    }
    haveRun = true;
    //A random function which should be loaded only once.
  };
})();
```

```js
const initStandardProviders = (() => {
  let haveRun = false;
  return () => {
    if (haveRun) {
      return;
    }
    haveRun = true;
    //A random function which should be loaded only once.
    console.log('running main function body');
  };
})();

initStandardProviders();
initStandardProviders();
initStandardProviders();
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)